# Convert binary survey results to character vectors in an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, character, binary-data, tidyverse

Suppose I have the result of a supermarket fruit stock survey stored in a data frame:

```
stock <- data.frame(
    store = c("Asda", "Booths", "Co-op"),
    apple = c(1, 0, 0),
    banana = c(1, 1, 0),
    coconut = c(0, 0, 0)
)
```

which looks like

```
   store apple banana coconut
1   Asda     1      1       0
2 Booths     0      1       0
3  Co-op     0      0       0
```

**My goal:**

I want to convert the above columns of binary survey results into a character vector of stock summary for each supermarket as below:

```
   store        fruits
1   Asda apple, banana
2 Booths        banana
3  Co-op
```

**My solution:**

*Step 1:* I used a `for` loop to replace all 1s in the binary columns with the corresponding column names:

```
for(i in names(stock)[2:4]) {
    stock[which(stock[[i]] == 1), i] <- i
}
```

and got

```
   store apple banana coconut
1   Asda apple banana       0
2 Booths     0 banana       0
3  Co-op     0      0       0
```

*Step 2:* I use `tidyr::unite()` to concatenate the individual fruit columns into a character vector column:

```
library(tidyverse)
stock <- unite(stock, fruits, apple:coconut, sep = ", ")
```

giving me

```
   store           fruits
1   Asda apple, banana, 0
2 Booths     0, banana, 0
3  Co-op          0, 0, 0
```

*Step 3:* I had to use stringr::str_replace_all() to remove all unwanted 0s and comma separators:

```
library(stringr)
stock$fruits <- str_replace_all(stock$fruits, "0, |, 0|0", "")
```

Although this could get me the result I want, I find my solution rather clumsy, especially the looping part. Could anyone kindly share with me a more efficient and straightforward solution, please? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task requires to reshape the input data from wide to long format.

Although the question is explicitely tagged with `tidyverse`, I would like to start with a concise `data.table` solution using `melt()` which I'm more acquainted with:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(stock), id.vars = "store")[
  value > 0, .(fruits = toString(variable)), keyby = store][.(stock$store)]
```

> ```
>     store        fruits
> 1:   Asda apple, banana
> 2: Booths        banana
> 3:  Co-op            NA
> ```

It coerces `stock` to class `data.table` and reshapes it from wide to long format. Then, only rows which have at least one fruit are considered in the subsequent aggregation where the result is grouped by `store`. `toString()` is used for aggregation which is a concise alternative to `paste()`. In order to include *all* stores, even those without any fruit, a final right join is required.

---

The same goal can be achieved by using functions from the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages as requested by the OP:

```
library(magrittr)
stock %>% 
  tidyr::gather(fruits, , -store) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(value > 0) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(store) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(toString(fruits)) %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(stock %>% dplyr::select(store))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>    store `toString(fruits)`
>   <fctr>              <chr>
> 1   Asda      apple, banana
> 2 Booths             banana
> 3  Co-op               <NA>
> ```

Both results are equivalent.

Note that references to `tidyverse` functions are made explicit in order to avoid name conflicts due to a cluttered name space.

Comment: Thanks SO much for kindly offering two solutions to my question while paying considerate attention to my question tags, and for your extra coding comments explaining things clearly! Although my preferred `tidyverse` solution is pretty neat, I am also amazed by the conciseness of the `data.table` alternative.

Comment: @elarry To be honest, I prefer `data.table` not only for its concise code but also for performance reasons for larger problems. E.g., see [my benchmark of a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44755588/3817004).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming unique store names, only 1s and 0s, and no missing values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- stock %>%
  gather(fruit, binary, -store) %>%
  mutate(fruit = if_else(binary == 1, fruit, NA_character_)) %>%
  select(-binary) %>%
  filter(!is.na(fruit)) %>%
  group_by(store) %>%
  summarize(fruits = paste(fruit, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(stock %>% select(store)) %>%
  mutate(fruits = if_else(is.na(fruits), "", fruits))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing a `paste()` alternative for converting the binary data to character vectors - it's particularly useful for people like me who don't know the `toString()` function. :)