# Fast and efficient way to expand a dataset in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I try to expand a dataset in R using the values from different columns (Key2 - KeyX) and then use the column number in a formula do compute some value.

Example of a part of the dataset I want to expand

```
Year Key2 Key3 Key4 Key5 ...
2001  150  105  140  140
2002  130   70   55   80
2003  590  375  355  385
...
```

Preferred result.

- i = index number
- col = column number (Key2 = 1, Key3 = 2, etc.)
- p = random number
- value = value calculated with the column number and p

  ```
  year   i col         p     value
  2001   1   1 0.7481282 4.0150810
  2001   2   1 0.8449366 2.0735090
  2001 ...   1 0.1906882 0.9534411
  2001 150   1 0.8030162 3.7406410
  2001   1   2 0.4147019 4.2246831
  2001   2   2 0.3716995 1.8584977
  2001 ...   2 0.5280272 2.6401361
  2001 105   2 0.8030162 3.7406410
  2001   1   3 0.7651376 3.8256881
  2001   2   3 0.2298984 1.1494923
  2001 ...   3 0.5607825 2.8039128
  2001 140   3 0.7222644 3.6113222
  etc.

  2002   1   1 0.1796613 0.8983065
  2002   2   1 0.6390833 3.1954165
  2002 ...   1 0.5280272 2.6401367
  2002 130   1 0.4238842 2.1194210
  2002   1   2 0.7651376 3.8256889
  2002   2   2 0.2298984 1.1494928
  2002 ...   2 0.5607825 2.8039125
  2002  70   2 0.7222644 3.6113227
  2002   1   3 0.7512801 3.7564000
  2002   2   3 0.4484248 2.2421240
  2002 ...   3 0.5662704 2.8313520
  2002  55   3 0.7685377 3.8426884
  etc.
  ```

I use the following code in R, but it is very slow with a large dataset.
I tried to keep the use of loops to a minimum by using `rep()` but I still have to for-loops in the code.

Is there a faster / more efficient way to do this is R? Using data.table?

```
val <- c(); i <- c(); cols <- c(); p <- c(); year <- c()
for (year in 1:10) {
  for (n in 2:25) {
      c <- n-1
      pu <- runif(dataset1[[year, n]])
      p <- c(p, pu )
      tmp <- (c-1)*5 + 5*pu
      val <- c(val, tmp)
      ##
      i <- c(i, 1:dataset1[[year, n]])
      cols <- c(cols, rep(c, dataset1[[year, n]]) )
      year <- c(year, rep(dataset1[[year,1]], dataset1[[year, n]]) )
  }
}
res.df <- data.frame(year=year, i=i, cols=cols, p=p, val=val)
res.df <- setDT(res.df)
```

Comment: You really really need to vectorize your code. You can easily create everything up to the `p` and `value` stage in a vectorized manner. For instance `library(data.table) ; res <- setorder(melt(setDT(DT), id = "Year", value = "i", variable = "col")[rep(1:.N, i)], Year, col)[, i := seq_len(.N), by = .(Year, col)]`. I don't understand how are you creating `p` and `value`, but `runif` is **vectotrized**, **don't use loops** in order to run vectorized actions. You can create both of these columns in a single call if you could explain what on earth are you actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for the `data.table` suggestion. So much faster than loops. Some more background information. The values in the initial dataset represent the number of people in a certain age group with a range of 5 years. Key2: age 0-5 yrs; Key3: age 5-10 yrs; etc. With the formula, I try to simulate the ages for the individuals in each category.

Comment: I would like to add this question as well, as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175658/efficient-way-of-appending-rows-to-data-table
Perhaps you could speed up some of the calculations, by only expanding the data.table if there are no more empty rows available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a row by reference at the end of a data.table object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792001/add-a-row-by-reference-at-the-end-of-a-data-table-object)

Comment: @hannes101 I don't believe this is a good dupe target. The question is _not_ about adding rows at the end of a data.table but to create a substantially larger data set, i.e., the above 3 rows are eventually expanded to a new data set of 2575 rows which is a 900-fold increase. However, using `data.table`'s fast `set()` operation might be an alternative to the other answers. If you post a solution I'll be happy to include this in my benchmark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core of the problem is the expansion of the values in the `Key` columns into `i`.

Here is another `data.table` solution employing `melt()` but differing in implementation details from [David's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747009/fast-and-efficient-way-to-expand-a-dataset-in-r#comment76475174_44747009):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dataset1)
expanded <- melt(DT, id.vars = "Year", variable = "col")[, col := rleid(col)][
  , .(i = seq_len(value)), by = .(Year, col)]
expanded
```

> ```
>       Year col   i
>    1: 2001   1   1
>    2: 2001   1   2
>    3: 2001   1   3
>    4: 2001   1   4
>    5: 2001   1   5
>   ---             
> 2571: 2003   4 381
> 2572: 2003   4 382
> 2573: 2003   4 383
> 2574: 2003   4 384
> 2575: 2003   4 385
> ```

The remaining computations can be done like this (if I've understood OP's intention right)

```
set.seed(123L) # make results reproducable
res.df <- expanded[, p := runif(.N)][, value := 5 * (col - 1L + p)][]
res.df
```

> ```
>       Year col   i         p     value
>    1: 2001   1   1 0.2875775  1.437888
>    2: 2001   1   2 0.7883051  3.941526
>    3: 2001   1   3 0.4089769  2.044885
>    4: 2001   1   4 0.8830174  4.415087
>    5: 2001   1   5 0.9404673  4.702336
>   ---                                 
> 2571: 2003   4 381 0.4711072 17.355536
> 2572: 2003   4 382 0.5323359 17.661680
> 2573: 2003   4 383 0.3953954 16.976977
> 2574: 2003   4 384 0.4544372 17.272186
> 2575: 2003   4 385 0.1149009 15.574505
> ```

---

### Benchmarking the different approaches

As the OP is asking for a *faster / more efficient way*, the three different approaches proposed so far are being benchmarked:

- [David's `data.table` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747009/fast-and-efficient-way-to-expand-a-dataset-in-r#comment76475174_44747009) plus a modification which ensures the result is identical with the expected result
- [ycw's `tidyverse` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44747199/3817004)
- my `data.table` solution

#### Benchmark code

For benchmarking, the `microbenchmark` package is used.

```
library(magrittr)
bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  david1 = {
    expanded_david1 <-
      setorder(
        melt(DT, id = "Year", value = "i", variable = "col")[rep(1:.N, i)], Year, col
      )[, i := seq_len(.N), by = .(Year, col)]
  },
  david2 = {
    expanded_david2 <-
      setorder(
        melt(DT, id = "Year", value = "i", variable = "col")[, col := as.integer(col)][
          rep(1:.N, i)], Year, col)[, i := seq_len(.N), by = .(Year, col)]
  },
  uwe = {
    expanded_uwe <- 
      melt(DT, id.vars = "Year", variable = "col")[, col := rleid(col)][
        , .(i = seq_len(value)), by = .(Year, col)]
  },
  ycw = {
    expanded_ycw <- DT %>%
      tidyr::gather(col, i, - Year) %>%
      dplyr::mutate(col = as.integer(sub("Key", "", col)) - 1L) %>%
      dplyr::rowwise() %>%
      dplyr::do(tibble::data_frame(Year = .$Year, col = .$col, i = seq(1L, .$i, 1L))) %>%
      dplyr::select(Year, i, col) %>%
      dplyr::arrange(Year, col, i)
  },
  times = 100L
)
bm
```

Note that references to `tidyverse` functions are made explicit in order to avoid name conflicts due to a cluttered name space. The modified `david2` variant converts factors to numbers of levels.

#### Timing the small sample data set

With the small sample data set with 3 years and 4 `Key` columns provided by the OP the timings are as follows:

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>    expr       min         lq        mean    median         uq        max neval
>  david1   993.418  1161.4415   1260.4053  1244.320   1350.987   2000.805   100
>  david2  1261.500  1393.2760   1624.5298  1568.097   1703.837   5233.280   100
>     uwe   825.772   865.4175    979.2129   911.860   1084.226   1409.890   100
>     ycw 93063.262 97798.7005 100423.5148 99226.525 100599.600 205695.817   100
> ```

Even for this small problem size, the `data.table` solutions are magnitudes faster than the `tidyverse` approach with slight advantages for solution `uwe`.

The results are checked to be equal:

```
all.equal(expanded_david1[, col := as.integer(col)][order(col, Year)], expanded_uwe)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(expanded_david2[order(col, Year)], expanded_uwe)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(expanded_ycw, expanded_uwe)
#[1] TRUE
```

Except for `david1` which returns factors instead of integers and a different ordering, all four results are identical.

#### Larger benchmark case

Form OP's code it can be concluded that his production data set consists of 10 years and 24 `Key` columns. In the sample data set the overall mean of `Key` values is 215. With these parameters, a larger data set is being created:

```
n_yr <- 10L
n_col <- 24L
avg_key <- 215L
col_names <- sprintf("Key%02i", 1L + seq_len(n_col))
DT <- data.table(Year = seq(2001L, by = 1L, length.out = n_yr))
DT[, (col_names) := avg_key]
```

The larger data set returns 51600 rows which is still of rather moderate size but is 20 times larger than the small sample. Timings are as follows:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>    expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
>  david1    2.512805    2.648735    2.726743    2.697065    2.698576    3.076535     5
>  david2    2.791838    2.816758    2.998828    3.068605    3.075780    3.241160     5
>     uwe    1.329088    1.453312    1.585390    1.514857    1.634551    1.995142     5
>     ycw 1641.527166 1643.979936 1646.004905 1645.091158 1646.599219 1652.827047     5
> ```

For this problem size, `uwe` is nearly twice as fast as the other `data.table` implementations. The `tidyverse` approach is still magnitudes slower.

Comment: Great answer and comparison.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer and clear explanation. This code runs so much faster than my original code.

Comment: Hi @UweBlock, I have another approach from `tidyverse` using `map2` and `unnest`. Please see my update in my answer. Would you mind if you also do benchmarking for this one? There is no dought that `data.table` is faster, but I think it would be good to know if it is a good rule to avoid `rowwise` and `do` if possible.

Comment: @ycw Yes, you're welcome. My idea is to add benchmark runs for larger problem cases by varying the 3 parameters which influence the problem size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea. `df2` contains the expanded `Year`, `col`, and `i`. You can further create `p` and `value` for `df2`.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "Year Key2 Key3 Key4 Key5
2001  150  105  140  140
                 2002  130   70   55   80
                 2003  590  375  355  385",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 


# Expand the data frame
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(col, i, - Year) %>%
  mutate(col = as.numeric(sub("Key", "", col)) - 1) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data_frame(Year = .$Year, col = .$col, i = seq(1, .$i, 1))) %>%
  select(Year, i, col) %>%
  arrange(Year, col, i)
```

#### Update

Another approach from the `tidyverse`.

```
# Expand the data frame
dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(col, i, - Year) %>%
  mutate(col = as.numeric(sub("Key", "", col)) - 1) %>%
  mutate(i = map2(1L, i, seq, by = 1)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(Year, i, col) %>%
  arrange(Year, col, i)
```